# Why is this ComboBox rendering the SelectedItem directly as content, instead of using the ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` displaying a list of items. I've created a converter to map from this object type to a `string` value.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedDrawing.Icons}" Name="TrackElementSelector" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource LayoutElementToStringConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The problem is that when I select/click a value in the `ComboBox`, the `ComboBox` renders the `SelectedItem` directly (it's a `UserControl` defined elsewhere in my project). For example, imagine seeing a literal `Button` after clicking the string element "Button" on the `ComboBox`. I do not want this behavior.

Why isn't the `ItemTemplate` being used here? It seems like the `ItemTemplate` is only used until a value is selected.

---

I've discovered another unexpected result. When I drop down the `ComboBox` to make a selection, the instances where the controls appear in other places of my application *disappear*. I'm wondering if there's something more complex going on due to stuff in my codebase, or if this is all consequence of trying to display `UserControl` objects inside a `ComboBox`.

Comment: What is the type of the _control defined elsewhere in my project_?

Comment: It's a class which inherits from UserControl and implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

    public class LayoutElement : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
...
}

Comment: And it has an associated XAML view defined.

Comment: Are the itemsource objects WPF visuals or data objects? It's unconventional to bind to a collection of WPF visuals and also be using a data template. Wouldn't surprise me if WPF just ignored the data template for the selected item if it's a visual.

Comment: @EmperorEto they are visual objects. I think you're right, it's a case WPF wasn't expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You discovered an interesting behavior of the the `ComboBox` control. When binding items, how the items are presented sometimes depends on their type. For example, if you bind items that are already of type `ComboBoxItem`, it will not create additional containers, since that would be redundant. This is a common design decision for other `ItemsControl`s as well.

## Why Item Template is Ignored

However, your issue originates from a different special treatment of the selected item in `ComboBox` regarding [`ContentControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)s. If the selected item is of this type or any of its direct or indirect derivatives (like [`UserControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)), `ComboBox` will use its `Content`, `ContentTemplate` and `ContentStringFormat`, instead of the [`ItemTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) or [`ItemStringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemstringformat?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) defined for the items on the `ComboBox` itself, thus ignoring the [`ItemTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

### Implementation Details

You can see this in the implementation of `ComboBox` within the [method `UpdateSelectionBoxItem`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ComboBox.cs,871):

```
// if Items contains an explicit ContentControl, use its content instead
// (this handles the case of ComboBoxItem)
ContentControl contentControl = item as ContentControl;

if (contentControl != null)
{
    item = contentControl.Content;
    itemTemplate = contentControl.ContentTemplate;
    stringFormat = contentControl.ContentStringFormat;
}
```

I do not know why it was implemented like this, but the original comment suggests that this might be intended to handle the case where the bound items are already `ComboBoxItem`. Maybe this behavior was not intented, but accidential.

### Solutions

If you wanted to change this behavior, you have these options:

1. Create your own custom implementation of `ComboBox`.
2. Add the item template to `UserControl` as content template as well.

   Although it works with the given implementation, it is sort of a hack.
3. Create a custom control template which ignores the special handling.

   You would create a copy of the default style and control template and adapt its `ContentPresenter`. By default it is bound to the special `SelectionBoxItemTemplate` property. You could ignore it by binding to the `ItemTemplate` property instead.

   ```
   <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                     Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"
                     ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                     ...>
   ```
4. Do not use a `ContentControl` or derived type for items, but use data templating with *data* items as source instead, as it is intended, see [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

   You should not bind UI elements as items source of the `ComboBox`. Instead, bind the data encapsulated in a model instead and provide a suitable data template to display it. The data could be an `Icon` class with a property `Path` or even simply a `string` representing the path.

   The data template could reuse your `UserControl` type to display it (if it is correctly implemented to bind data using its data context). This will result in a better design and will most likely eliminate the need for a value converter, too. Futhermore, it will solve your second issue automatically, the disappearing controls.

   **I strongly recommend you to use this option**, since it does not require any customization of framework elements and is much easier to do and maintain.

## Why Controls Dissappear

In WPF UI controls are attached to the so-called [visual tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/trees-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), which is a hierarchical object graph representation of your user interface. In this graph, each UI element instance can only have a **single parent**. Consequently, if you *"use"* an existing control in a different place, it is effectively reassigned to the corresponding parent be it in the same or a different visual tree (e.g. another window) and *"disappears"* from the original place.

Answer (score 1):

The source collection (`SelectedDrawing.Icons`) is not supposed to contain `UIElements`. Then the `ItemTemplate` is not applied.

The `UserControl` or the `Button` is supposed to defined in the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedDrawing.Icons}" Name="TrackElementSelector" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:UserControl1 />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The source collection should contain plain old CLR objects (POCOs), e.g.:

```
public class Icon
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Also note that an instance of a control can only appear *once* in the visual tree.